# AngularJS set form to initial state

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form which once submitted, I want to clear all fields and set to it initial state.

I use `$scope.form.setPristine();` but field labels keep red color.

[image]

How can I avoid this?

**EDIT**:

Here i post the code. All works fine except by such issue.

**Html**:

```
<form name="change_password" novalidate>
  <md-input-container style="margin:0;width:200px" flex>
    <label>Enter your current password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="7" required>

    <div ng-messages="change_password.password.$error" ng-if="change_password.password.$dirty" role="alert">
      <div class="error_form" ng-message="required">Enter your current password.</div>
      <div class="error_form" ng-message="minlength">Password must be at least 7 characters long.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container style="margin:0;width:200px" flex>
    <label>New Password</label>
    <input name="new_password" type="password" ng-model="new_password" ng-minlength="7" required>

    <div ng-messages="change_password.new_password.$error" ng-if="change_password.new_password.$dirty" role="alert">
      <div class="error_form" ng-message="required">Enter your new password.</div>
      <div class="error_form" ng-message="minlength">New password must be at least 7 characters long.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container style="margin:0;width:200px" flex>
    <label>Confirm new password</label>
    <input name="re_new_password" type="password" ng-model="re_new_password" ng-minlength="7" required>

    <div ng-messages="change_password.re_new_password.$error" ng-if="change_password.re_new_password.$dirty" role="alert">
      <div class="error_form" ng-message="required">Confirm your new password.</div>
      <div class="error_form" ng-message="minlength">New password must be at least 7 characters long.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <button  class="button" style="width:200px" ng-if="!saving" ng-click="save_password()" ng-disabled="is_uploading || change_password.$invalid || new_password!=re_new_password">Save new password</button>
  <div ng-if="saving" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" size="22"></md-progress-circular>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Ctrl**:

```
userService.save_password($scope.password, $scope.new_password).then( function(response) {
  $scope.$apply( function() {
    if ( response.result ) {
      $scope.password = '';
      $scope.new_password = '';
      $scope.re_new_password = '';
      console.info($scope.change_password);
      $scope.change_password.$setPristine();
    }
    showMessage(response);
    $scope.saving = false;
  })
})
```

Comment: "Enter your current password" reads as better English to me. May we have some code to look at?

Comment: @DanielShillcock Thanks! changed.

Comment: @domoindal This fiddle may help. http://jsfiddle.net/charms/AhGDC/24/

Comment: @DanielShillcock I do exactly the same than such example. What i do not understand is why labels get red once the form is reset.

Comment: `$scope.change_password.$invalid = false;` ?

Comment: @Georgy I tried your sentence and labels still in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset with $setPristine and $setUntouched (for your fiddle):

```
    $scope.user_form.$setPristine();
    $scope.user_form.$setUntouched();
```

Comment: Thanks! $setUntouched(); was the solution to avoiding red labels.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand

```
setPristine();
```

It only clears classes on your form, nothing else. Variables are still set. You need to do it like below:

```
$scope.emptyModel = {};
$scope.reset = function() {
   $scope.yourFormModel = angular.copy($scope.emptyModel);
   $scope.user_form.$setPristine();
   $scope.user_form.$setUntouched();
}
```